# How to redirect mail to another IP address

Tags: dns, email, mx

I want to redirect my site's mail server to another IP address. I setup an `MX` record for my mail server like this:

```
domain.org. IN  MX  1 mail.domain.org
```

But I do not know how redirect mail to another IP address like shown in this example DNS report: http://www.intodns.com/xilisoft.com

Answer (score 2):

MX record only sets the domain to use for emails. In your case you set it to mail.domain.org. To control what mail.domain.org resolves to, add separate A record or CNAME for mail.domain.org. E.g.

```
mail.domain.org. in A 123.45.67.89
```